# Download attribute inside span tag

Tags: html, anchor

It is possible to give download attribute inside span tag.

```
<a href = "image.jpg" download = "download_file_default_name">
```

The above element download image as download_file_default_name.

I want to change the above element as given below.

```
<span data-href = "image.jpg" download = "download_file_default_name">
```

So I can hide the link which looks under the left bottom of the page and i can give a default name for the downloading image.

Comment: What if you wrap your anchor tag using span tag ??

Comment: @MaulikBhatt it shows the download link at the left bottom of the montior screen, I dont want to show that. Both inside and outside span shows the link at the screen bottom.